# Intercept and modify USB packets

Tags: c#, vb.net, usb

The project is as follows;

I would like to create an application that will be able to see packets going to a USB device.  When a certain bit of data that is known is sent to the device, the returning data will be intercepted and modified before the application requesting it, gets it. I have used a USB sniffer to see the packets being sent and I know exactly what bits need to be changed. My two questions are;

1. Is this a possible software solution?
2. Will this have to be a hardware solution?

Additional Information –

- The USB device uses a FTDI245R chip for communication. I know the VID and PID of the device.
- I have experience programming in vb.net and C# but I have never done anything with USB
- I would like the application to be able to have a number entered and changed to hex data and that is what would be sent to the device. The number being entered would be changed frequently.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: it might be easier to do this at a higher level, would [hooking the function call to the USB device the application makes](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) be a option instead?

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure on the above mentioned way, but will look into it and let you know what I find. I forgot to mention the software is 3rd party along with the USB device, I am able to reprogram the USB device, but a software solution would be easier to share.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want an upper filter driver to the FTDI driver. I don't know what class or type of device you are using or if it has a vendor specific driver or not, but [here is a sample that shows how to create an upper filter to a vendor specific driver](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/umdffilterkmdf-f3100a1b). This example uses the OSRUSBFX2 device and sample driver in the WDK, you'll want to change the code to work and interface with the FTDI driver instead.